# Identifier 'originalPrompt' has already been declared (React TS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-tsx

In my project i  have no variable called "originalPrompt" but It keeps showing me this error
The issue appears for users with using "Selenium IDE" chrome extension
Is it possible to disable this extension for the user if he tried to visit my website?

[image]

Comment: No, your site can't disable an extension automatically.

Comment: so what's the right solution fo this issue? @AKX

Comment: Figuring out why exactly that happens and for your site only, and fixing the root cause.